# How to know when a MySQL user was last authenticated?

Tags: mysql

We have some distributed servers that connect to the same MySQL server. We need to have a log with the date/time when it was the last time a MySQL User logged in. How could I do that?

Comment: Do you want to have audit logs or just last date/time?

Comment: Just last date and time

Comment: Look for "authentication plugins"; they may have such features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using several ways:
Create general log and store there the info like in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/672):

> You would probably want to use the general query log.
>
> The general query log is a general record of what mysqld is doing. The server writes information to this log when clients connect or
>   disconnect, and it logs each SQL statement received from clients.
>
> One important thing with logging for security is that an attacker
>   cannot access the log to erase traces of their presence, so consider
>   append-only files.

Or create a table in to the database and store there every login via stored procedure as explained in [this web page](https://www.fromdual.com/last-login-off-mysql-database-users)

```
-- SET GLOBAL init_connect="";
SET GLOBAL init_connect="CALL tracking.login_trigger()";


DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE login_trigger()
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO login_tracking (user, host, ts)
  VALUES (SUBSTR(USER(), 1, instr(USER(), '@')-1), substr(USER(), instr(USER(), '@')+1), NOW())
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ts = NOW();
END;

//
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.